# Error using Range Method in VBA Excel (parameter setting)

Tags: excel, vba

I declared ColorCell variable and used Set in order to make some color change using For loop.

But it raises an error when coding it and I couldn't interpret the debug explanation.

```
Sub 계산()    
    Dim SumVariable As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim ColorCell As Range
    Set ColorCell = Range("D" & i)

    For i = 3 To Range("D14").End(xlUp).Row
        If Cells(i, "D") > 300 Then
            MsgBox ("haha!")

            Cells(i, "D").Value = 10
            Range("D4").CurrentRegion.Select
            ColorCell.Interior.Color = vbYellow                
        End If
    Next i    
End Sub
```

Comment: You have `Set ColorCell = Range("D" & i)` but `i` is zero at that point.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! Do I have to initialize it right after 
"Dim" declaration statement in that case ?

Comment: It’s not very clear what your code should do, but that line should probably be inside your loop.